# Вылетает приложение при попытке запуска новой активности

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent, recyclerview.adapter, context

Я сделал приложение в котором есть список музеев и парсер новостей. Все они переключаются с помощью `BottomNavigationBar`. При попытке нажатия на пункт списка приложение вылетает. Жалуется на строчку с непосредственным запуском новой активности через намерение. Что делать? Код и логи ошибок прилагаю ниже.

Лог ошибок

```
05-10 21:22:34.549 6113-6113/com.example.max.mainwindow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.max.mainwindow, PID: 6113
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.max.mainwindow/com.example.max.mainwindow.MuseumActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at com.example.max.mainwindow.MuseumAdapter$CardViewClickListener.onClick(MuseumAdapter.java:94)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        NewsParserFragment newsFragment = new NewsParserFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, newsFragment).commit();


    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_news:
                    Log.d("BottomNavigationBar", "Новости");

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    NewsParserFragment newsFragment = new NewsParserFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, newsFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_museums:
                    Log.d("BottomNavigationBar", "Музеи");

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                    ListFragment museumsListFragment = new ListFragment();
                    fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, museumsListFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_map:
                    Log.d("BottomNavigationBar", "Карта");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

ListFragment

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.museum_recycler_view);

        ArrayList<Museum> museums = new ArrayList<>();


        museums.add(new Museum("Музей плодового садоводства Среднего Урала","Октябрьской Революции, 40","3581774","https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-altay/374295/2a0000015b2eb298bed2092fcf13bcc347d7/XXL","www.uole-museum.ru","К сожалению, мы не нашли подробной информации о данном музее, но это никак не делает его хуже. Посетите его и узнайте все подробности сами :)"));
        museums.add(new Museum("Музей природы Среднего Урала","Горького, 4а","3712113","https://cdn00.mir.afisha.ru/imgs/2016/04/13/14/4907/40333dfdee4e8341d826560793d26c54a9f8650b.jpg","www.uole-museum.ru","Музей природы – старейшая среди площадок Свердловского областного краеведческого музея. За 146 лет его сотрудники собрали богатую естественнонаучную коллекцию – свыше 60 тысяч предметов. "));
        museums.add(new Museum("Уральский геологический музей (УГГУ)","Куйбышева, 39","2573109","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Уральский_геологический_музей_01.JPG/1600px-Уральский_геологический_музей_01.JPG","www.ursmu.ru","Музей при Уральском горном университете, содержащий богатую коллекцию геологических образцов Уральского региона. Насчитывает более 40 тысяч экспонатов. "));
        museums.add(new Museum("Уральский минералогический музей","Красноармейская, 1","3506019","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Гостиница_%22Большой_Урал%22.JPG/280px-Гостиница_%22Большой_Урал%22.JPG","www.pelepenko-va.ru","Частный минералогический музей, располагавшийся в Екатеринбурге с 2000 до 2015 года в здании гостиницы \"Большой Урал\". С 2017 года находится в Первоуральске в Инновационном культурном центре (известен как \"шайба\")"));


        MuseumAdapter museumAdapter = new MuseumAdapter(museums);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(museumAdapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        return view;
    }

}
```

MuseumAdapter

```
public class MuseumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MuseumAdapter.MuseumsViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Museum> museums;
    private Context context;

    public MuseumAdapter(ArrayList<Museum> museums){
        this.museums=museums;
    }

    @Override
    public MuseumsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new MuseumsViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final MuseumsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Museum museum = museums.get(position);

        holder.Name.setText(museum.getMname()+"\n");
        holder.Adress.setText("  Улица "+museum.getAdress());


        if(museum.getURL().isEmpty()){
            Picasso.get().load("https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp3w3Ok_TD46pLqIlFB7_TbbwUHQ4D867hKRhQ=s900-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no").into(holder.imgPoster);
        }else {
            Picasso.get().load(museum.getURL()).resize(640, 480).into(holder.imgPoster);
        }

        holder.cardViewClickListener.setRecord(museum);

    }

    public class MuseumsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Name, Adress;
        ImageView imgPoster;
        CardView cv;

        CardViewClickListener cardViewClickListener = new CardViewClickListener();


        public MuseumsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgPoster = itemView.findViewById(R.id.museum_poster);
            Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.museum_name);
            Adress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.museum_adress);
            cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.museum_list_item_cv);
            context=itemView.getContext();

            cv.setOnClickListener(cardViewClickListener);

        }
    }

    class CardViewClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        Museum museum;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MuseumActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", museum.getMname()); //name
            Log.d("INTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEENT", museum.getMname());
            intent.putExtra("URL", museum.getURL());
            intent.putExtra("trivia", museum.getTrivia()); //trivia
            intent.putExtra("website", museum.getWebsite()); //website
            intent.putExtra("phone", museum.getPhone()); //phone
            intent.putExtra("adress", museum.getAdress());


            ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);


        }

        void setRecord(Museum museum){
            this.museum=museum;
        }
    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return museums.size();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так у вас в логах все написано же

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.max.mainwindow/com.example.max.mainwindow.MuseumActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Вам надо `MuseumActivity` в манифесте объявить