# Приложение выдает ошибку и вылетает

Tags: java, android-studio, library

```
Вот такая ошибка выходит при нажатии на кнопку для перехода в активити с использованием библиотеки cropimage,piccaso.
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: testznaniya.app, PID: 14646
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {testznaniya.app/com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1737)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5445)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:712)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5395)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:693)
        at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage$ActivityBuilder.start(CropImage.java:487)
        at testznaniya.app.NameActivity$2.onClick(NameActivity.java:76)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7509)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7486)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:841)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28720)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14646 SIG: 9
```

Вот сам код активити

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageprofilreg;
    private EditText nameEdit;
    private Button buttonsavename;
    private StorageReference storageprofilpicsRef;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private String myUri = "";
    private String checker = "";
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
        imageprofilreg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageprofilreg);
        nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
        buttonsavename = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsavename);
        storageprofilpicsRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ProfileImage");
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserWoman-men");


        buttonsavename.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checker.equals("clicked")) {
                    ValidateControler();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        imageprofilreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checker = "clicked";
                CropImage.activity().setAspectRatio(1, 1).start(NameActivity.this);
            }
        });
        getUserInfo();
    }

    private void ValidateControler() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEdit.getText().toString()))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите ваше имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else if (checker.equals("clicked")) ;
        {


            uploadProfilImage();
        }
    }

    private void uploadProfilImage() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Идет загрузка");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Пожалуйста подождите");
        progressDialog.show();
        if (imageUri !=null){
            final StorageReference fileRef= storageprofilpicsRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"jpg");
            uploadTask=fileRef.putFile(imageUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw  task.getException();
                    }
                    return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <Uri>task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri=task.getResult();
                        myUri=downloadUri.toString();
                        HashMap<String,Object> userMap=new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("uid",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        userMap.put("name",nameEdit.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("image",myUri);

                        databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(NameActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Изображение не выбрано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private void getUserInfo() {
        databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)
                {
                    String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    nameEdit.setText(name);
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                        String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageprofilreg);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Синим выделена 76строчка но для наглядности весь код

```
imageprofilreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checker = "clicked";
                CropImage.activity().setAspectRatio(1, 1).start(NameActivity.this);
            }
        });
```

Отсюда выделена строчка с cropimage как это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вылетает приложение при попытке запуска новой активности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826147/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: Зарегистрируйте `CropImageActivity` в `AndroidManifest.xml` или добавьте ваш `AndroidManifest.xml` в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил. Теперь заработало но я фото не отправляется на firebase хотя все настроено